# Combine character if exist in list using regex Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, replace

How do I check if some string exist in text, and replace it? I have code like this:

```
import re

emoticon = [':)',':-)',':-(',':D']

def emoticonNormalize(text,loop=2):
    text = re.sub(r'\s(\S)\s(\S)\s(\S)\s', r' \1\2\3 ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\s(\S)\s(\S)\s', r' \1\2 ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\s(\S)\s(\S)', r' \1\2', text)
    print(text)

texta = 'I dont like politic : - ( but still read about it : - ) _ because its funny . : D and unpredictable : )'
print(texta)

texted = emoticonNormalize(texta,1)
```

code result:

```
I dont like politic : - ( but still read about it : - ) _ because its funny . : D and unpredictable : )
I dont like politic :-( but still read about it :-) _because its funny .:D and unpredictable :)
```

so, the string in `texta` contain character that actually an **emoticon** but **it still separated by space**. I am trying to combine the look like emoticon using regex.

I am imagine to find the suspect emoticons first. Then check if its in the `emoticon` list or not, if its in the list, replace the old pattern (still have space between) with combine one.

I am confuse how to do it using `re.sub`, the **expected result** is `I dont like politic :-( but still read about it :-) _ because its funny . :D and unpredictable :)`

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You produced the expected result, so what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Are you expecting this result?  `I dont like politic :-( but still read about it :-) _ because its funny . :D and unpredictable :)`

Comment: @l'L'l yes but i am not check the suspect yet to emoticon list. its also remove space in `_because` and `.:D` which are not emoticons.

Comment: @SahilGulati yes, I am expecting that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I've passed `re.sub()` a regular expression that matches the emoticons you would like to tighten and a function `tighten_emoticon`, which removes the spaces between each character of the matching regex object.

```
import re

def tighten_emoticon(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(0).replace(" ", "")

original = 'I dont like politic : - ( but still read about it : - ) _ because its funny . : D and unpredictable : )'

tightened = re.sub(r'(: - \(|: - \)|: D|: \))', tighten_emoticon, original)
```

**EDIT**

Optionally, you can build the regular expression on the fly, using your `emoticon` list:

```
emoticon = [':)',':-)',':-(',':D']

REGEX = '|'.join([re.escape(' '.join(x)) for x in emoticon])

tightened = re.sub(REGEX, tighten_emoticon, original)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work fine.

```
import re

emoticon = [':)',':-)',':-(',':D']

def emoticonNormalize(text,loop=2):
    text = re.sub(r'\:\s*D', ':D', text)
    text = re.sub(r':\s*\-\s*\)', ':-)', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\:\s*\-\s*\(', ':-(', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\:\s*\)', ':)', text)
    print(text)

texta = 'I dont like politic : - ( but still read about it : - ) _ because its funny . : D and unpredictable : )'
print(texta)

texted = emoticonNormalize(texta,1)
```

Output:

```
I dont like politic : - ( but still read about it : - ) _ because its funny . : D and unpredictable : )
I dont like politic :-( but still read about it :-) _ because its funny . :D and unpredictable :)
```

Comment: What have you changed from the original post?

Comment: @waterboy5281 I have changed the expression. Earlier approach was not appropriate. There was no reason for vote down. Someone asked a question and came up with expected result.

Comment: @waterboy5281 It is not required to changed the format of the answer but it is to solve with desired output.

Comment: @SahilGulati thanks for the answer, it is a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\:)( )','',texta)
Out[72]: 'I dont like politic :- ( but still read about it :- ) _ because its funny . :D and unpredictable :)'
```